# Reading into C# XML output from stored procedure returns null from TEMP tables SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns the below output:

```
DECLARE @ExistingXML XML =
(
    SELECT TOP 2 * 
    FROM #xmlInput 
    FOR XML PATH('Record'), ROOT('Records'), ELEMENTS
);

DECLARE @XmlWithDeclaration VARCHAR(MAX) =
(
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>'
           +
           '<test>hello</test>'
           --CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@ExistingXml)
);


SELECT @XmlWithDeclaration;
```

When the `'<test>hello</test>'` is used it works perfectly fine. But when the data is read from the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@ExistingXml)` statement. It never returns the value from the temp table. However this stored procedure - when executed from SSMS - shows the output perfectly fine.

I am trying to read this through below code. Please ignore the `@ReportID` as it is a dummy thing which I am trying to do .

```
string xmlResult = await DLContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec [dw].[spPROCName] @ReportID"
                   , new SqlParameter("@ReportID", 8)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlResult))
    Console.WriteLine($"XML RESULT :{xmlResult}");
else
    Console.WriteLine("--Failed--. No Result or null");
```

It always shows the else part and not the positive scenario where I can get the two results .

Any idea why ?

Update : 
Another thing is , above code works perfectly fine when I pull data from Physical tables . However it fails for Temporary tables since temporary table data is getting inserted upon parsing a 6MB xml File . Could that be the reason ?

Comment: Does the temporary table contain anything? THere's no difference between temp and permanent tables. Post a *reproducible* example that contains the table creation command and sample data

Comment: When you say that you run it under SSMS and it works fine, do you mean you run the SP in SSMS, or you copy the code from the SP into SSMS and run it like a script?  Also, in both cases, are you looking at the same data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the issue is resolved apparently it was found that there was XML transformation was not taken care properly . So this question is resolved

Answer (score 0):

As per your coding you are using temp table in Sql server.
Temp Table is Self Destroy after Session is close.
So You have to use different Scenario.